# Extending multiple grails DataSources in DataSources.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource

Every environment you define in `DataSource.groovy` extends the base `dataSource` definition at the root of the file, outside of environments.

I have two specific configurations that I need to apply to a number of different environments which have minor environment-specific changes. Really, I need two "base definitions", or some way to extend existing definitions.

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

```
dataSource1 {
    dbCreate = "update"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    pooled = false
    jndiName = "java:something"
}
dataSource2 {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    //extend datasource1
    production{
    }
    //extend datasource2
    development{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will assign dataSource1 and dataSource2 a Closure (note the =) and you could then call them within your environment blocks.

```
dataSource1 = {
    dbCreate = "update"
    driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
    dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    pooled = false
    jndiName = "java:something"
}

dataSource2 = {
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
            username = "sa"
            password = ""
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
}

environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            dataSource1.call()
        }
    }
    development {
        dataSource {
            dataSource2.call()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was actually trying to do just this, but I guess I screwed up syntax or something. Thanks much!

Comment: How is this different than just putting the dataSource closure inside the env blocks?

Comment: @Gregg - it is different because it makes the config re-usable - you can create connections to n different databases with the same basic config

Comment: Great answer. Would you be able to show how to move the closures such as dataSource1 to another file (script or class)? I have tried moving them inside a class such as OracleConfig and then doing `new OracleConfig().dataSource1.call()` but I get messages such as `No such property: dbCreate for class: ... OracleConfig`. I have been trying to get this working for several hours and also haven't found anything to solve this on SO. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The dataSource closure can exist within the environemnts closures...

```
environments {
   production {
      dataSource {
         dbCreate = "update"
         dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
         pooled = false
         jndiName = "java:something"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Then maybe you didn't explain yourself clearly enough?  I made an attempt.  Thanks for the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an outside config file for Grails(instead of Config.groovy) and define the dataSource inside it. To do that, we can write the following code in Config.groovy

```
if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
    grails.config.locations = ["file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]]
}
```

Then at the deployed environment, define the environment variable: `${appName}.config.location`. That environment variable point to the outside config file.