# Sharing environment settings in datasource.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-orm

So we are able to create different environment settings in the datasource.groovy file.  And we can put common settings outside the environments node like so

```
dataSource {
   pooled = false
   driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
   username = "sa"
   password = ""
}
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
           url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

But is there a way to so that we can have certain enviroments share some properties while others share a different set of properties such as having a shared set between developers (Omar, and Stringer in this case):

```
dev_dataSource {
   pooled = false
   driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
   username = "dev"
   password = "dev"
}
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
   username = "sa"
   password = "something"
}
environments {
    omar {
        dataSource {
            dev_dataSource {
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@omardb.wire.com:1521:devl"
            }
        }
    }
    stringer {
        dataSource {
            dev_dataSource {
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@stringerdb.wire.com:1521:devl"
            }
        }
    }
    devint {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: See update to my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Sergio's approach, you can also use `datasource` as you have expected for respective users during development assuming you use `run-app` by following this command:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=omar run-app //uses Omar's datasource
grails -Dgrails.env=stringer run-app //uses Stringer's datasource
```

**UPDATE**
The way to tailor the datasource in order to access `datasource_dev` is bit tricky here. You have to take care the way ConfigSlurper reads the ConfigObject.

```
dataSource_dev {
   pooled = false
   driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
   username = "dev"
   password = "dev"
}
dataSource {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
   username = "sa"
   password = "something"
}
environments {
    omar {
        //You do not need this if you only want to use dev's datasource 
        //dataSource { 
            dataSource_dev {
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@omardb.wire.com:1521:devl"
            }
        //}
    }
    stringer {
        //You do not need this if you only want to use dev's datasource
        //dataSource {
            dataSource_dev {
                url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@stringerdb.wire.com:1521:devl"
            }
        //}
    }
    devint {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the above setup you can very well inherit the default properties from `datasource_dev` for `omar` environement.

Grails converts/reads the above configuration and ends up with:

```
[
    dataSource_dev: [
        pooled: false,
        driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
        username: "dev",
        password: "dev",
        url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@omardb.wire.com:1521:devl"  //<-- Omar's setting
    ],
    dataSource: [
        pooled: true,
        driverClassName: "org.h2.Driver",
        username: "sa",
        password: "something"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Yes I know how to run code for separate environments, I'm just wondering if they can inherit properties from a different default datasource than the rest of the environments are using.

Comment: @JimSosa yes they can. Any config outside the environments block will be available for all.

Comment: Hmmm...  @DMahapatro, Now that I look at this, that's kind of taking advantage of the multiple datasources aspect, but does that mean I need to change all my domain classes to use both datasources or the 'ALL' configuration.  Or can I just make a global mapping some where for this?

Comment: Yes that is the caveat. Otherwise you can move, all contents from `datasaource_dev` and put to each environment (omar, stringer) under `omar{datasource{....}}` which will be redundant as obvious. @JimSosa

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do that [externalizing you configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized). Load different files according with the current environment.

```
if(Environment.current in ['omar','stringer']) {
  grails.config.locations = [
    'file: path/to/DevelopersConfig.groovy'
  ]
}
```

And in your file you can declare any configuration needed, including the dataSource.

Another option is to setup a single environment and use it for both developers. This will eliminate the need of a external config file.

**EDIT**

Now I saw again you config file, I think that you just need to adjust omar and stringer configs:

```
omar {
  dataSource_dev {
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@omardb.wire.com:1521:devl"
  }
}
```

Since it's a different dataSource it should not be inside a dataSource block. Looking [at the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) it seems that you need to set a suffix and not prefix to your multiple datasources.

Comment: LOL. I am tail-gating you today. :-) Looks like I am the lazier coder than you. :P

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  Not sure I love having to manage separate config files, but it would meet the requirements.  Is there any way to do it in one config file though?  Having developers share an environment doesn't work as they actually have their own dbs.

Comment: @JimSosa See my edit. I think that's just an adjustment in your configs.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I meant I am giving one liner alternative's to your answers, therfore lazy. ;)

Comment: @dmahapatro I see now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using closures as below:

```
devDataSourceConfig = { // Note the equals sign!
   pooled = false
   driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
   username = "dev"
   password = "dev"
}
standardDataSourceConfig = {
   pooled = true
   driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
   username = "sa"
   password = "something"
}

environments {
    omar {
        dataSource {
            devDataSourceConfig.call()
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@omardb.wire.com:1521:devl"
        }
    }
    stringer {
        dataSource {
            devDataSourceConfig.call()
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@stringerdb.wire.com:1521:devl"
        }
    }
    devint {
        dataSource {
            standardDataSourceConfig.call()
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            standardDataSourceConfig.call() 
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            standardDataSourceConfig.call()
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb"
        }
    }
}
```

Similar question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331868/extending-multiple-grails-datasources-in-datasources-groovy).