# Extending environments in Grails

Tags: grails

In Grail it is possible to have many environments in your Config.groovy

```
environments {
    development {
        ...
    }
    test {
        ...
    }
    myenv {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I make one environment extend another?  By extend I mean `myenv` wants all the properties of `development` that aren't already common between `test` and `development` and just adds one more.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by 'extend' another?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore have updated question

Answer (score 0):

Can you try some thing like this...

```
   def dbSource = dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        }
```

environments {
    development {
        dbSource
    }
    test {
        dbSource
    }
    myenv {
        dbSource
    }
}

Also refer to this answer I found ...

[Sharing environment settings in datasource.groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18366128/sharing-environment-settings-in-datasource-groovy)